re train and fine tune layout llm v3 based on documents
I possess a collection of scanned document images that resemble forms and receipts, adhering to a uniform layout. My objective is to identify and annotate header sections while extracting relevant text from these images, leveraging the functionality of Form and Receipt Understanding via LLMV3.
To accomplish this task, I've prepared labeled training data utilizing Label Studio. Each entry in my JSON file corresponds to an individual image, containing information such as:
Bounding boxes surrounding specific regions within the image
Textual content present within those bounding boxes,
json file=[
    {
        "id": "22.PNG","file_name": r"\22.PNG", "annotations": [
            { "box_id": 1,"text": "S-4","bbox": [76.35082251821494, 1.912568306010929, 23.64917748178506,4.553734061930783],
                "category_id": "label1" }, { "box_id": 2,"text": "tiktok","bbox": [76.35082251821494, 1.912568306010929, 23.64917748178506,4.553734061930783],
            "category_id": "label2" }
            }]

Associated labels assigned to each box, kindly provide correct my code to predict boxes and thier lables from new image acheive these objective using llmv3 and torch
label_map={ "lable1":0, "lable1":2,"lable3":2,"lable4":3,"lable5":4,"lable6":5,"lable7":6, "lable8":7,"lable9":8,
    "lable10":9,"lable11":10,"lable12":11,"lable13":12,"lable14":13,"lable15":14,"lable16":15,"lable17":16,"lable18":17,"lable15":19}
    os.environ['TORCH_HOME'] = r"D:\\DL_ML_Projects\\torch"
    device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
    os.environ['TORCH_HOME'] = r"D:\\DL_ML_Projects\\torch"
    device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
    
    # torch.set_default_tensor_type(torch.cuda.FloatTensor if device == 'cuda' else torch.FloatTensor)
    
    class CustomDataset(Dataset):
        def __init__(self, annotations, processor):
            self.annotations = annotations
            self.processor = processor
            self.images = []
            self.bboxes = []
            self.labels = []
            self.words=[]
            for annot in annotations:
                # Load images and prepare bboxes and labels
                img_path = annot['file_name']
                id =  annot['id']
                img = Image.open(img_path).convert('RGB')
                # img = Image.open(img_path).convert('L')
                resized_img = img.resize((512, 512), resample=Image.BILINEAR)
                bboxes_coords = [[bbox['bbox'][0], bbox['bbox'][1], 
                                  bbox['bbox'][0] + bbox['bbox'][2], 
                                  bbox['bbox'][1] + bbox['bbox'][3]] 
                                 for bbox in annot['annotations']]
                # words_extracted = [bbox['text'] for bbox in annot['annotations']]
                words_extracted = [bbox["category_id"] for bbox in annot['annotations']]
                labels=[label_map.get(bbox["category_id"],-1) for bbox in annot['annotations']if bbox["category_id"] in label_map]
                # print(words)
                self.images.append(resized_img)
                self.bboxes.append(bboxes_coords)
                self.words.append(words_extracted)
                # self.labels.append([0]*len(bboxes_coords))
                self.labels.append(labels)
    
                # print ( id,labels)
    
        def __len__(self):
            return len(self.images)
    
        def __getitem__(self, idx):
            max_length=512
            # zipped_lists = zip(self.words, self.images, self.labels, self.bboxes)
            # sorted_zipped_lists = sorted(zipped_lists, key=lambda x: x[2])  # Sort by self.labels
            # self.words, self.images, self.labels, self.bboxes = [[item[i] for item in sorted_zipped_lists] for i in range(4)]
            # print(self.words[idx],self.labels[idx])
           
            # bboxes = torch.tensor(self.bboxes[idx]).int()
            bboxes = torch.tensor(self.bboxes[idx]).long().to(device)
            encoding = self.processor(images=self.images[idx],
                                      boxes= bboxes,
                                      text=self.words[idx],
                                      return_tensors="pt", 
                                      word_labels =torch.tensor(self.labels[idx], dtype=torch.long),
                                    #   labels=torch.tensor(self.labels[idx], dtype=torch.long)
                                      )
        
            # encoding['labels'] =torch.tensor(self.labels[idx])
           
            return {key: val.squeeze() for key, val in encoding.items()}
    
    # Load annotations
    with open(r'D:\\DL_ML_Projects\\ocr_surface_geology_samples\\Batch_2\\output-updated.json', 'r') as f:
        annotations = json.load(f)
    
    # os.environ['CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING'] = '1'
    
    # Initialize the LayoutLMv3 processor
    model_path = r"D:\\DL_ML_Projects\\layoutlmv3_model\\models--microsoft--layoutlmv3-base\\snapshots\\cfbbbff0762e6aab37086fdd4739ad14fe7d5db4"
    processor = LayoutLMv3Processor.from_pretrained(model_path, apply_ocr=False)
    
    # Create your dataset
    dataset = CustomDataset(annotations, processor)
    # data_collator= DataCollatorWithPadding(processor=processor,padding=True)
    
    data_collator= DataCollatorWithPadding(processor.tokenizer,padding=True)
    # Load the model
    model = LayoutLMv3ForTokenClassification.from_pretrained(model_path,num_labels=19)
    # Define training arguments
    training_args = TrainingArguments(
        save_total_limit=2,
        output_dir='./results',
        evaluation_strategy="epoch",
        save_strategy="epoch",
        fp16=True,
        learning_rate=0.001,
        per_device_train_batch_size=5,
        num_train_epochs=20,
        weight_decay=0.001,
        remove_unused_columns=False,
        # metric_for_best_model="overall_f1",
        
    
    )
    
    # Use the Trainer API
    trainer = Trainer(
        model=model,
        args=training_args,
        train_dataset=dataset,
        eval_dataset=dataset,
        data_collator=data_collator
          # Pass your dataset here
    )
    
    # Train the model
    trainer.train()
    processor.feature_extractor.apply_ocr = True
    # Save processor and create model card
    processor.save_pretrained('./results')
    trainer.create_model_card()

